# how can I group together an image and it's text so that they can s

Tags: html, css, image, text, hover

Below (jsfiddle) is a css + html code that showcases a number of gray-scale images and it's title. Functionally, upon hovering over the image, the image's true color is restored, and the title gets replaced by a subtitle and detail. Through CSS, this is achieved by using `:hover`.

The effect works fine, and it seems to be showing no issues / glitches, but when the cursor hovers over the title, the image goes back to being gray-scale yet replaces the title with its subtitle and detail. I'm wondering **1) how I can make both the image and text one element**, **2) how can I add the fade-in fade-out effect to the text**, and finally **3) upon hovering over the image, is it possible the images stay colored (not gray-scale)**?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/j1r7es4j/) I have set up. Please let me know if there are other references / resources / modifications I can make for clarification. Thanks in advance!

*— On a sidenote, Happy Thanksgiving! I'm definitely thankful for StackExchange's amazing community — You all helped me so much over the past few months and I wanted to thank you all for your generosity. I hope that one day I'll get good at coding to the point I will be able give back by helping others. Cheers!*

**CSS**

```
section.image ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5% 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
section.image li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
section.image li img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
section.image li img:hover {
    filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
}
section.image li span.caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
section.image li:hover span.caption {
    display: block;
}
section.image li span.caption.label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    font-family:'Phenotype S', times;
}
section.image li:hover span.caption.label {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="image">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img width="80%" height="100%" src="http://asset2.itsnicethat.com/system/files/022013/5114e1305c3e3c262a000631/img_col_main/3.-Nov.-2008.jpg?1360323002" class="attachment-full" alt="selected_image" title="selected_image" /> 
            <span class="caption label">Title</span>
            <span class="caption">Subtext<br/>Detail</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="30%" height="100%" src="http://asset2.itsnicethat.com/system/files/022013/5114e1375c3e3c262a000632/img_col_main/6.-Nov.-08.jpg?1360323004" class="attachment-full" alt="selected_image" title="selected_image" />
            <span class="caption label">Title</span>
            <span class="caption">Subtext<br/>Detail</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="70%" height="100%" src="http://asset2.itsnicethat.com/system/files/022013/5114e13a5c3e3c22a3000bdf/img_col_main/10.-Nov.-08-(reverse).jpg?1360323005" class="attachment-full" alt="selected_image" title="selected_image" />
            <span class="caption label">Title</span>
            <span class="caption">Subtext<br/>Detail</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="90%" height="100%" src="http://asset1.itsnicethat.com/system/files/022013/5114e13d5c3e3c22a3000bfc/img_col_main/10.-Nov.-08.jpg?1360323006" class="attachment-full" alt="selected_image" title="selected_image" /> 
            <span class="caption label">Title</span>
            <span class="caption">Subtext<br/>Detail</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your margins to padding (if you think about how the box model works, this should make sense). I also changed the `li image:hover` to `li:hover img`

http://jsfiddle.net/j1r7es4j/2/

```
body {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 100%;
    color: #222222;
}

section.image ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5% 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
section.image li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
section.image li img {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -o-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.9);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
section.image li:hover img {
    filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0.1) brightness(1);
}
section.image li span.caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
section.image li:hover span.caption {
    display: block;
}
section.image li span.caption.label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    font-family:'Phenotype S', times;
}
section.image li:hover span.caption.label {
    display: none;
}
```